# IPv6 DNS resolve - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: network-manager, dns, ipv6, systemd-resolved

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm not getting IPv6 to work.
Can someone help me, please?

**$ resolvectl -6 query google.com**

```
google.com: 2a00:1450:4003:801::200e           -- link: wlo1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 16.2ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

OK

**$ resolvectl -6 query askubuntu.com**

```
askubuntu.com: resolve call failed: 'askubuntu.com' does not have any RR of the requested type
```

FAIL

**$ resolvectl -4 query askubuntu.com**

```
askubuntu.com: 151.101.1.69                    -- link: wlo1
               151.101.65.69                   -- link: wlo1
               151.101.193.69                  -- link: wlo1
               151.101.129.69                  -- link: wlo1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 18.3ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

OK if IPv4 is used.

```
$ cat /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
$ cat /var/run/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

[Output when connected using IPv4]

```
$ cat /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
$ cat /var/run/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

[Output when connected using IPv6]

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS                 
DefaultRoute setting: yes                 
       LLMNR setting: yes                 
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
         DNS Servers: 2001:4860:4860::8888
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

**$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**EDIT:**
There was a problem. I could not access askubuntu.com website.
The problem was on my NetworkManager configuration. I've set the IPv4 method as "disabled", when I what I really intended was to only "Require IPv6 addressing for this connection to complete". Cool behavior though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking from here, it doesn't seem askubuntu.com has any AAAA (IPv6) DNS records.  Not everything does, after all.  So it's not that you haven't visited it before, it's that it just doesn't exist for anybody.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I revised the post since I was making wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Use dig and specify AAAA as the record type to determine if the issue is network related or system related.

```
root@ubuntu:~# dig google.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64485
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             240     IN      AAAA    2607:f8b0:4006:804::200e

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 06 21:21:59 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

If this works it will at least narrow down the scope of your issue.